# Replace Apache CXF with Sun Metro in TomEE

Tags: cxf, java-metro-framework, apache-tomee

I have faced a problem in our development project today. I wanted to create webservice in TomEE 1.6.0+ environment in the same way as I did earlier in Glassfish environment. I had a lot of trouble with it so I thought I try to replace Apache CXF with Sun Metro stack (version 2.3).

I haven't found any tutorial on it so I tried to do something myself. My solution was to delete all of the cxf-*.jar and openejb-cxf-*.jar from the TomEE lib folder and I have added webservices-*.jar (only the following 4 libraries: rt, tools, extra, extra-api) from the metro distribution. I have looked into the installation ant script and I have selected files based on the installation definition.

It looks now everything is perfect. Now I can work the same way with webservices as I worked before. My project deploys smoothly into TomeEE environment.

My question is quite simple now:

Is it a correct solution or looks like a hack?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer would come from someone on the TomEE project, but I'm surprised this worked... but I'm happy it did for you.

TomEE has bindings to CXF for CDI for specific purposes: it can scan for jax-rs annotations, inject fields, expose services, etc (too many to enumerate). As long as your application isn't reliant on any of that functionality, you might be ok.

Since you're running an unsupported configuration, the key here is thorough testing. I would create a battery of integration tests (SOAP-UI?) that will get you a comfortable level of branch coverage... definitely at least cover your happy paths.

The nice thing about TomEE is that it's incredibly modular as you discovered. Good luck, and post back for the community how everything is going later on.

Comment: Yes, you are right: without apache-cxf jax-rs annotations really failing but of course this is trivial consequence because there is no jax-rs implementation. So I did some more experiments. I have changed back the apache-cxf libraries. Now when I include any jax-rs resource all of my url-s destroyes because I have root context. When I have deleted the jax-rs resource class, the urls are good again. And the webservice works good, but webservice clients give me policy error "None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied" so none all of the functionality are available. I need more research.